# rsync with --delete-before except if source empty

Tags: rsync, delete

I back up a hard drive with an rsync --delete-before cron job. The problem is that if the source drive fails then rsync sees it as empty and everything is deleted from the backup - exactly what you don't want to happen. I would like to rather have a cron job run a script that only runs the rsync command if the source is not empty. Is it possible to get some help writing the script?

Comment: In case of errors with the source drive, rsync will not proceed. In case you specify a mountpoint as source, but the drive is not mounted, rsync will indeed see an empty source directory. Actually, the format of this site is question - answer. It is not suited to interactively help you to build a script. For that, you better ask this in a forum.

Comment: Thanks. Yes. I do specify a mount point as the source. So specifying the device as source (eg /dev/sdc1) would avoid my issue? Good to know. In the meantime I have done some googling and managed to write a bash script that emails me (using msmtp) if the mount point is empty - so that I know there is  an issue - and runs the rsync command if the mount point is not empty.

Comment: Add that information to your question: use "edit". An easier approach is to place the content you want to backup in a folder *under* the mount  point (i.e., under a folder on the disk). That way, the backup will fail if the drive is not mounted. With symbolic links, it is easy enough to still access the data where you want to access them.

Comment: Thanks. Add which information to my question? I'm not sure what you mean about putting the source data under (in?) a folder on the disk / mount point. My data is in a set of folders under the mount point - and I have had the whole backup deleted in the past when the source drive wasn't mounted.

Comment: The information that you specify a mount point as the source. And eventually how that drive is mounted (automounted? fstab?). That explains the behavior you observe.

Answer (score 2):

If your source drive fails, then `rsync` will abort. The only scenario where `rsync` will continue even when the folder is empty, is when that folder is a mount point for a hard drive, but that hard drive happens not to be mounted.

You can of course do a little scripting to check whether the drive is mounted or not, but a more straightforward safeguard against this pitfall would be not to use a mount point as the source for `rsync`.

Instead, either have several `rsync` commands backup each folder under the mount point, or, better, move all the content of the root of that partition (files and folders you see in the mount point) to a single subfolder. Then you can backup all contents by backing up that subfolder. If the drive happens not to be mounted, the subfolder (source for `rsync`) will not be there and `rsync` will not proceed (erasing your destination).

It is easy enough to still access the data where you want it to be: use symbolic links.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify source path with a `..` like this:
`rsync [opts] /mnt/source/.somedirectory/../ /mnt/target/backup/`
you can pick any folder that already exists and you will never delete

if source is not mounted, the subdirectory will not exist (unless something else puts it there), the operation will fail because it cannot access part of the path. (hopefully the behavior never changes -- you should verify it, you could combine it with checking if it is mounted, which has a race condition though.)

theoretically then unmounting should not be possible once rsync changes directory to it, but i am not sure of the behavior if it does disappear while running, likely will just error out. should have at least two copies of source, anyway.